# Room cannot verify the data integrity when re open the app

Tags: android, kotlin

i'm learn how to use Room from [Codelabs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin/)
and now i have two table

when i'm run from Android Studio is normal

**but when i'm close and re open the app i got error**

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Room cannot verify the data integrity. Looks like you've changed schema but forgot to update the version number. You can simply fix this by increasing the version number.

**error when re open the app**, not on install

i'm try to up version number and i still got the error

here my code

```
@Database(entities = [Type::class], version = 3)
abstract class TypeRoomDb : RoomDatabase(){

    abstract fun typeDao() : TypeDao

    companion object{
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE : TypeRoomDb? = null

        fun getDataBase(
            context: Context,
            scope: CoroutineScope
        ): TypeRoomDb {
            return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this){
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    TypeRoomDb::class.java,
                    Cons.DB_NAME
                )
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .addCallback(TypeDbCallBack(scope))
                    .build()
                INSTANCE = instance

                instance
            }
        }

        private class TypeDbCallBack(
            private val scope: CoroutineScope
        ) : RoomDatabase.Callback(){
            override fun onOpen(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                super.onOpen(db)
                INSTANCE?.let { database ->
                    scope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                        populateDb(
                            database.typeDao()
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        fun populateDb(typeDao: TypeDao){
            typeDao.deleteAll()
            /*out*/
            typeDao.insert(
                Type(
                    "000",
                    "Makan",
                    0
                )
            )
            typeDao.insert(
                Type(
                    "001",
                    "Transportasi",
                    0
                )
            )
            typeDao.insert(
                Type(
                    "002",
                    "Makanan Ringan",
                    0
                )
            )
            typeDao.insert(
                Type(
                    "003",
                    "Komunikasi",
                    0
                )
            )

            /*in*/
            typeDao.insert(Type(
                "500",
                "Gaji",
                1))
            typeDao.insert(
                Type(
                    "5001",
                    "Hadiah",
                    1
                )
            )
        }

    }
}
```

my second table

```
@Database(entities = [LogKeuangan::class], version = 2)
abstract class LogKeuanganRoomDb : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun logKeuanganDao(): LogKeuanganDao

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: LogKeuanganRoomDb? = null

        fun getDataBase(
            context: Context,
            scope: CoroutineScope
        ): LogKeuanganRoomDb {
            return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    LogKeuanganRoomDb::class.java,
                    Cons.DB_NAME
                )
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .build()

                INSTANCE = instance
                instance
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything clearly mentioned in

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Room cannot verify the data integrity. Looks like you've changed schema but forgot to update the version number. You can simply fix this by increasing the version number.

All you need to is increase version and set `exportSchema` to `false`

from

```
@Database(entities = [Type::class], version = 3)
```

to

```
@Database(entities = [Type::class], version = 4, exportSchema = false)
```

Note

> @Database creates another db if you want all tables belongs same db
>   then include them into one db. you should not create new db for each
>   table

Comment: i'm already tried that
i'm run from Android Studio is normal
but when i'm close the app and reopen from my phone not from Android Studio, i got that error

Comment: @Database creates another db if you want all tables belongs same db then include them into one db. you should not create new db for each table

Comment: so just use 1 RoomDatabase class?

Comment: its work, deleted second RoomDatabasee class
thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

If you've changed your schema then you'll need to supply migration classes to update the existing data to match the schema:

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions

```
//EXAMPLE TAKEN DIRECTLY FROM THE LINK SUPPLIED:

val MIGRATION_1_2 = object : Migration(1, 2) {
    override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
        database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE `Fruit` (`id` INTEGER, `name` TEXT, " +
                "PRIMARY KEY(`id`))")
    }
}

val MIGRATION_2_3 = object : Migration(2, 3) {
    override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE Book ADD COLUMN pub_year INTEGER")
    }
}

Room.databaseBuilder(applicationContext, MyDb::class.java, "database-name")
        .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2, MIGRATION_2_3).build()
```

You could also uninstall the app manually before reinstalling with the DB changes, and then you won't need to concern yourself with migration until the app is published.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to [Jasurbek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8342718/jasurbek)

i'm deleted my second RoomDatabase class, and add my second table to entities

and it's done

```
@Database(entities = [Type::class, LogKeuangan::class], version = 3)
abstract class TypeRoomDb : RoomDatabase(){

    abstract fun typeDao() : TypeDao
    abstract fun logKeuanganDao() : LogKeuanganDao
```